# first loop not working

Tags: javascript, netsuite

My Inner loop seems to work fine, but once the inner loop is complete i expect the first loop to start again but it doesn't and it's not clear to me why...

```
if(search)
{
    // loop through Revenue Arrangements
    for (var x = 0; search != null && x < search.length; x++)
    {
        var revenue_arrangement = nlapiLoadRecord('revenuearrangement', search[x].getValue(columns[0]));
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Revenue Arrangement Internal ID', search[x].getValue(columns[0]));

        var count = revenue_arrangement.getLineItemCount('revenueelement');
        for (var x = 1; x <= count; x++)
        {
           var rev_element_id = revenue_arrangement.getLineItemValue('revenueelement', 'transactionline', x);               

            if(rev_element_id)
            {
                nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Element Internal ID', rev_element_id);
            }
        }
  nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'End of Inner Loop);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the JS console for any errors? Also note that your copy/pasted snippet has a typo (missing closing quote in: `'End of Inner Loop`)

Comment: Thanks - fixed the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reusing the `x` variable and the nested iteration affects the outer one. This was stated clearly in other answer, but let's extend this to point to two aspects of javascript you might be not aware of, but you should:

1. Javascript uses block operators `{}` but it does not implement block
   scope. This means that a for loop does not create a new variable
   scope. This is significant if you come from c/c++ background.

   See more:
   http://doctrina.org/JavaScript:Why-Understanding-Scope-And-Closures-Matter.html
   *(also see for closures, that is how outer scope affects nested function scopes)*.
2. Javascript hoists variable declarations to the beginning of a
   function scope. This means both of `var x` are effectively declared
   in the very beginning of the snippet included in the question (or
   possibly even earlier).

   See more:
   http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

   Extra var hoisting example which shows how *bizzare* can be its effects: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

---

The above means that your code (simplified) of this:

```
var search = ["a","b","c","d"], count;
if(true) {
    for (var x = 0; x < search.length; x++){         
        count = 2;
        for (var x = 1; x <= count; x++){            
           console.log("innner", x)
        }      
        console.log("outer", x)
    }
}
```

is the same as this:

```
var search = ["a","b","c","d"], count, x = 1;
if(true) {
    for (; x < search.length; x++){

        count = 2;
        for (; x <= count; x++){            
           console.log("innner", x)
        }      
        console.log("outer", x)
    }
}
```

That means you don't *only* have two loops that affect each other. You're also ignoring the 0 element of the first array (the `var x = 1` in nested loop overrides `var x = 0` in the outer).

Both snippets will output:

```
innner 1
innner 2
outer 3
```

Comment: Since the inner loop is iterating over a NetSuite sublist, 1 is the correct starting index.

Answer (score 7):

your both loops (inner and outer) are using the same variable as counter (`x`)

Use different counter variables for both

```
if(search)
{
    // loop through Revenue Arrangements
    for (var x = 0; search != null && x < search.length; x++)
    {
        var revenue_arrangement = nlapiLoadRecord('revenuearrangement', search[x].getValue(columns[0]));
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Revenue Arrangement Internal ID', search[x].getValue(columns[0]));

        var count = revenue_arrangement.getLineItemCount('revenueelement');
        for (var y = 1; y <= count; y++)
        {
           var rev_element_id = revenue_arrangement.getLineItemValue('revenueelement', 'transactionline', y);               

            if(rev_element_id)
            {
                nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Element Internal ID', rev_element_id);
            }
        }
  nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'End of Inner Loop);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the super quick response - I can stop pulling hair out now!